# Equivalent categories but not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, functors

Let **Mat** be a category where the objets are the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ and for each pair $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ the morphism $m \rightarrow n$ is a matriz $M_{nm}$ of size $n \times m$. Let $Vec_{\mathbb{R}}$ be the category of finite dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ where the morphisms are linear transformation.

It is a well known result that these categories are equivalent defining the functor $F: \boldsymbol{Mat} \rightarrow Vec_{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $Fn = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $FM_{nm}$ is the linear transformation that has the matrix $M_{nm}$ as the matrix representation.

My question is, are these categories isomorphic? I think the answer is no, of course, but in order to prove it, is there any result from which the statement follows directly? Or should I propose the existence of two functors $F,G$ such that $GF$ and $FG$ are the corresponding identities morhpisms and get a contradiction? Thanks

Comment: Hint: Which objects in $\mathbf{Mat}$ are isomorphic? What about $\mathbf{Vect}_{\mathbb{R}}$?

Comment: @QiZhu I understand the hint. In **Mat** we have a countable set as objects. But what's the "size" of $\mathbf{Vec}_{\mathbb{R}}$? Should I see this as the size of the class that collects all vector spaces up to isomorphisms?

Comment: That's unfortunately not what I meant. See Thorgott's comment to his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mathbf{Mat}$ has countably many objects, whereas $\mathbf{Vec}_{\mathbb{R}}$ has a proper class of objects. An isomorphism of categories is in particular a bijection on objects, so cannot exist between these.

Comment: Thanks. What's the "size" of the class $\text{Objects}(\mathbf{Vec}_{\mathbb{R}})$? I mean the ojects are vector spaces, so for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ fixed, I have only one vector space up to isomorphisms, $\mathbb{R}^n$. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what notion of "size" you have in mind, it being a proper class is enough to know. In fact, we can get away with much more coarse information. I'm not sure what point you're trying to make after. Even for a fixed $n$, there is only one vector space up to isomorphism (and what an equivalence does is only consider things up to isomorphism), but there is a proper class worth of vector spaces of that given dimension (which an isomorphism considers).

Comment: Put differently (and this is what Qi Zhu's point is as well): if two objects in $\mathbf{Mat}$ are isomorphic, they are *equal*. The same is not true in $\mathbf{Vec}_{\mathbb{R}}$, but an isomorphism would preserve this property.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking on $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \text{Objects}(\mathbf{Vec}_{\mathbb{R}})$ and see that this can't be a bijection. Since $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, then the result follows if, for example, the cardinality of $\text{Objects}(\mathbf{Vec}_{\mathbb{R}})$ is greater then $\aleph_0$. I'm not sure I get your definition of a proper class...

Comment: @Ejrionm A proper class is a class which is not a set (think back to Russell's paradox, some things are too large to be contained in a set). In category theory parlance, $\mathbf{Mat}$ is a small category while $\mathbf{Vec}_{\mathbb{R}}$ is not.

Comment: I don't think there's a sensible notion of "cardinality" for proper classes. Here's an explicit argument for why the objects of $\mathbf{Vec}_{\mathbb{R}}$ form a proper class that might clear things up: Namely, the cass of all sets injects into the class of objects of $\mathbf{Vec}_{\mathbb{R}}$. Ineed, for every set $X$, you can consider the singleton set $\{X\}$ and consider it a $0$-dimensional vector space with the trivial operations. But $\{X\}\neq\{Y\}$ if $X\neq Y$ by the axiom of extensionality.